# Can't resolve the main.xml after eclipse restart

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I have a problem. Yesterday I opened eclipse to go on with an app I am making, but then some errors popped up which never appeared before (it worked fine when I closed it the last time). Since then the errors didn't go away. I cleaned eclipse, restarted it and so on. Here are two of the errors (one is with the activity_main and one with main):

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}
```

**I already removed android.R and cleared eclipse!!** because some people said I should try it.
What should I do? I am pretty sure there is a problem with the "R." because everytime I remove it the errors go away but then the "R." gets marked as an error.

Comment: Did you possibly move a class outside the application package because R works in the application package and not in com.example.myapp.utilities  Also in eclipse there is the compare to local history.  Yesterday should be there to compare with.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the R file because probably one of your resources has an error.Please review all your layouts,drawables and menu resources carefully to see if u did anything wrong.